# WooCommerce checking for match in spreadsheet

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a question about woocommerce and was hoping someone could help me out.

I have set up a Wordpress website and installed Woocommerce. 
But I need help with the following issue.
I have an Excel spreadsheet with 96.000 numbers. When a customer is ordering something from the woocommerce shop, they will be asked to provide a number (not a required field). I need woocommerce to check if the provided number matches one of the 96.000 numbers in the Excel spreadsheet. And if it does find a match, the customer should get 10% discount.
I would not mind losing the spreadsheet if there is a good solution without using the spreadsheet.

Does someone have any tips on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use the coupon feature in woocommerce. I personally have not used this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-coupons-bulk-editor/ - but it looks like you can use this to upload your spreadsheet and each number would act as a coupon code that gave the 10% discount.

There is also a woocommerce plugin called Smart Coupons that does that as well. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/smart-coupons/how-to-import-coupons-in-bulk-using-a-csv-file/

I'm sure you could find a free download of it somewhere to at least try it out.